# tsql - Using a variable in an update statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an update statement like this:

```
UPDATE CompaniesHouse     SET   
   LastOccurrence       =(select top 1 Id from Dataset ORDER BY RowNum DESC),

   CompanyName          =QCompaniesHouseUpdate.CompanyName,
   FirmId               =QCompaniesHouseUpdate.FirmId,
   ...
   PreviousCompanyDate  =QCompaniesHouseUpdate.PreviousCompanyDate,
   PreviousCompanyName  =QCompaniesHouseUpdate.PreviousCompanyName

FROM  QCompaniesHouseUpdate Join CompaniesHouse
ON    (QCompaniesHouseUpdate.FirmId=CompaniesHouse.FirmId)
```

GO

I tried to save the nested query to a variable and use that instead like this but it didn't work:

```
declare @dataset int
select top 1 @dataset =  Id from Dataset ORDER BY RowNum DESC
```

When I tried to use the variable in place of the nested query I got the message:

```
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 135
Must declare the scalar variable "@dataset".
```

It's not that important, but there are other places where it would also be useful. I'm also slightly worried that it's getting evaluated for every insertion and later on in the code, for every update. 
It would also be useful to have the declaration at the top of the code once in case I need to change it.

Comment: Are you executing the update statement in a different batch? Don't see why you would get that error otherwise.

Comment: What you've shown looks fine. At a guess, the bit you've *not* shown is the cause of the error - have you placed a `GO` between your `declare`/`select` and the `update`?

Comment: you probably need to create a variable to hold the sql string, something like Set @sql='Update...' + @dataset + 'rest of the query'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Damien_The_Unbeliever had the right answer - I had lots of GO statements in my code, thinking they were needed at the end of update statements, etc. but they aren't. This removed the variables I had set at the start.

More info: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx

Answer (score 0):

-- Try this, i just changed the order of join and set Alias to table CompaniesHouse (Rest seems ok to me)

```
declare @dataset int
select top 1 @dataset =  Id from Dataset ORDER BY RowNum DESC
UPDATE C     SET   
   LastOccurrence       =@dataset,

   CompanyName          =QCompaniesHouseUpdate.CompanyName,
   FirmId               =QCompaniesHouseUpdate.FirmId,
   ...
   PreviousCompanyDate  =QCompaniesHouseUpdate.PreviousCompanyDate,
   PreviousCompanyName  =QCompaniesHouseUpdate.PreviousCompanyName

FROM  CompaniesHouse C JOIN QCompaniesHouseUpdate  
ON    (QCompaniesHouseUpdate.FirmId=CompaniesHouse.FirmId)
```

Comment: This doesn't change anything to the outcome of the query, and thus also not a valid answer

Comment: why would this help with the issue of using a varible in the nested query?